# Connecting STM32F7 with SIM7600 by USB

Tags: usb, driver, stm32, cellular-network, stm32f7

Has anyone tried to connect sim7600 LTE module with STM32f7 by USB HS?

Simcomm has developed USB drivers for Windows/Linux/Android but not for ordinary microcontrollers such as STM32.

STM32F7 has the USB HS Host ability.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

STM32F7 has partial USB HS support and need external phy driver. Full support is provider only through full speed. You should not have any problem once you have a usb stack working on the micro ( st free usb library probably is not going to be enough )

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The HW is of no problem. The main difficulty is the driver. The module needs to act as a dial up modem and requires a modem kind driver.

Comment: Both if you plan to use circuit switched data or packet switched data, you should be fine with few AT command (strings) on a CDC-ACM usb profile provided that module has an TCP/IP stack, otherwise you should look for a software stack to compile on the MCU.

Comment: CDC-ACM USB profile won't work, and AT command is not for transmitting with high data rate. I am looking for a software stack but I'm afraid there is no one, and I think I have to write it myself.

Comment: You're right. If you don't need many simultaneous connections some modules implement trasparent modes which can bind a CDC-ACM I/O directly to a socket. If this is not the case I'm afraid you need a mux.